# PHPUnit can't found the "TestCase" class

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

To run my tests using the project's PHPUnit I do the following : `php vendor/bin/phpunit tests/SomeClassTest.php` which works fine given the following class declaration :

```
class SomeClassTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
  public function test_someMethod() {}
}
```

But it fails when I do this :

```
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class SomeClassTest extends TestCase {
  public function test_someMethod() {}
}
```

I get `PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase' not found`...

Comment: What version of PHPUnit you're using?

Comment: @Martin PHPUnit 4.8.24

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Class `TestCase` exists since PHPUnit 5.4. You can see it on github if you set [5.3 tag](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/tree/5.3/src) (look for `ForwardCompatibility` folder) or you can compare doc for [5.3](https://phpunit.de/manual/5.3/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html) and [5.4](https://phpunit.de/manual/5.4/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html) in the `2. Writing Tests for PHPUnit` section where it says:

*"ClassTest inherits (most of the time) from PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase."* for PHPUnit 5.3

and

*"ClassTest inherits (most of the time) from PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase."* for PHPUnit 5.4

Answer (score 3):

In my library that I still have marked as usable by PHP 5.4, I've had to add this to my top-level testcase class in order to bridge the non-namespaced / namespaced difference, depending on which version of PHPUnit gets installed by Composer based on the runtime PHP version.

```
/*
 * Allow for PHPUnit 4.* while XML_Util is still usable on PHP 5.4
 */
if (!class_exists('PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase')) {
    class PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase extends \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase {}
}

abstract class AbstractUnitTests extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
```

This works fine on PHP 5.4 (PHPUnit 4.8.34) up to PHP 7.1 (PHPUnit 6.0.2).