# Use \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase or ..\TestCase

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

Stupid question...  In the Symfony docs, unit test classes extend `\PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase` but in PHPUnit docs, test classes extend `PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase`.  Is there a difference, are they the same, or am I missing a subtle PHP feature where `_` is equivalent to `\`?

Short of actually testing it out myself, can I use either, or just one in Symfony?

**Update**:  It's been helpfully explained to me that these two classes are just a difference between PHPUnit versions.  After my own research and for the record, Symfony 3.1 still extends `\PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase` in its own `KernelTestCase` class that powers Symfony's functional testing.  To avoid breaking code, I'm going to play safe & extend `WebTestCase` that inherits from `\PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase` when unit testing with Symfony specifically. Such unit tests still work with PHPUnit 5.6 anyway

Comment: You can also use the approach from the answer to the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42811164/class-phpunit-framework-testcase-not-found/42828632#42828632

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the same but since PHPUnit 5.4 it's recommended to use `TestCase`. However, it's not a problem if you stay with `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase`.

See a very similar question: [PHPUnit can't found the "TestCase" class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40045163/phpunit-cant-found-the-testcase-class/40045423#40045423)

Comment: So this is a case of legacy Symfony notes falling behind on PHPUnit changes?

Comment: If Symfony2 uses `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase` somewhere that it's because it an old code or maybe their tests aren compatible with PHPUnit 5.4+.

Comment: I'll look into it carefully, especially the composer config to see what version it installed for the project.  I'm technically using Symfony 3.1, but even StackExchange only shows the symfony2 tag.  Update:  Composer deferred to the global installation of PHPUnit, didn't install a local copy.  My global version is 5.6

Comment: Since my package's unit tests had to run on PHPs from 5.4 through 7.1, I found a workaround so that the tests as written would work across those versions -- http://stackoverflow.com/a/42030041/108146